# sysctl.conf not surviving reboot

Tags: 20.04, kde

I have several options laid out in my /etc/sysctl.conf but for some reason they aren't surviving a reboot. I'm mainly measuring this by ipv6 being active on my network interface every time I boot despite disabling it on all interfaces in my sysctl.conf.
I have checked sysctl.d for other configurations but the files in there don't seem to be doing anything to alter my settings in sysctl.conf.

/etc/sysctl.d/*

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77 Feb 27  2020 10-console-messages.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  761 Nov 16 16:54 10-kernel-hardening.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  257 Feb 27  2020 10-link-restrictions.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1184 Feb 27  2020 10-magic-sysrq.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1292 Feb 27  2020 10-ptrace.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  506 Feb 27  2020 10-zeropage.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Oct  8 15:14 99-sysctl.conf -> ../sysctl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  792 Feb 13  2020 README.sysctl
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
#

# Disable IPv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

# Spoof protection (reverse-path filter). Source Address Verification in all interfaces
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5

# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1

# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1

# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Log Martian Packets
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
```

$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-*.conf | egrep -v #

```
kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
kernel.sysrq = 176
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was here, but I disabled and removed Network-Manager and now the sysctl settings are applied correctly.